# regex works on regex tester but not in c++

Tags: c++, regex, quotes

I am trying to get the content between quotes from a file, and I am using regex. This is the regex I am using:

```
id=\"([^\"]+)\"|title=\"([^\"]+)\"
```

As you can see, every special character is escaped. It works perfectly in regex tester, but when used in c++ code the title isn't found. ID is always found just fine. I have tried several variations, and even removed half of it (before |)

```
id="60973129" title="EPA"
```

This is the C++ code that I am using:

```
std::regex rgx("id=\"([^\"]+)\"|title=\"([^\"]+)\"");
std::smatch match;

if (std::regex_search(line, match, rgx)) {
    for (int i=0; i < match.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << match[i];
    }
}
```

EDIT: I found that if put separately, the `title=\"(.+?)\"` does work, but then I have to use several regexes, which defeats my purpose, since I will need to scan longer lines later.

Comment: Can you show the code where it is actually used ?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but this could be simplified by using non-greedy repeats. Instead of `\"([^\"]+)\"` try `\"(.+?)\"`.

Comment: It's probably just an issue with the snippet, but it looks like you're passing `match2` into regex_search, then iterating over `match`.

Comment: Yes this is just a mistake between snippets. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

It probably works in a tester because it's saying "does anything match" within the string, as opposed to "does the entire thing match".

Anyway, | is an "or", find one or the other. To match the string as shown, change | to either a space, or an indicator for any amount of whitespace, such as [ \t]+ and I suspect it will work fine then.

Comment: I am getting no results with neither `id=\"([^\"]+)\" title=\"([^\"]+)\"` nor `id=\"([^\"]+)\"[ \t]+title=\"([^\"]+)\"`